# Current post number/total posts single.php Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So Im trying to display current post number and total posts in a category while in single.php view.

Lets say I have a category of 5 cars (posts), Im viewing car 2, previous post is car 1, next post is car 3, total cars 5.

In wordpress, how can I show that your currently view car 2 of 5?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to [so]. On Stack Overflow, we ask that if you'd like some help with your code, that you post your current code, what you expect to occur, the issue with your current code and what you've tried to do to fix it. If you could edit your question to include these things, that would improve your question greatly. Thank you!

Comment: After hours of searching, the answer can be found here:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35522/post-x-of-y-in-single-php-sidebar-php#new-answer